# Creating an element and adding it an event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having problems adding an event to a dynamically created element in Javascript. This is the code:

```
var monto=document.createElement('input');
monto.type='text';
monto.name='monto'+cantpagos;
monto.id='monto'+cantpagos;
if(monto.addEventListener) monto.addEventListener("blur", sumpagos, false);
else if(monto.attachEvent) monto.attachEvent("onblur", sumpagos);
document.getElementById('pagos').appendChild(monto);
```

However it's not working, once I remove the focus the function is not called. What am I doing wrong? Thanks beforehand.

EDIT: This is more relevant code:

```
function sumpagos()
{
   var total=0;
   for(var i=1;i<=cantpagos;i++)
   {
      total+=document.getElementById('monto'+i).value;
   }
   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML="$"+total;
}

function addpago()
{
var i = 0;
var cuota=document.createElement('select');
cuota.name="cuota"+cantpagos;
cuota.id="cuota"+cantpagos;
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
   cuota.options[i-1]=new Option("Cuota "+i, i);
}
document.getElementById('pagos').appendChild(cuota);
var monto=document.createElement('input');
monto.type='text';
monto.name='monto'+cantpagos;
monto.id='monto'+cantpagos;
if(monto.addEventListener) monto.addEventListener("blur", sumpagos, false);
else if(monto.attachEvent) monto.attachEvent("onblur", sumpagos);
document.getElementById('pagos').appendChild(monto);
document.getElementById('pagos').innerHTML+="<br />";
cantpagos++;
}
```

---

```
<td id="total">
$0
</td>

<input type="button" name="maspago" value="Añadir un Pago" onclick="addpago();" />
<input type="button" name="memospago" value="Eliminar un Pago" onclick="deletepago();" />
<div id="pagos"></div>
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/tm2Gg/).

Comment: You've excluded relevant javascript and HTML. There's nothing visibly wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: patrick, I'm gonna post the affected boxes and functions.

Comment: @Carlos Is the function `sampagos` defined? What does `typeof sampagos` give you?

Comment: Does your browser report an error? <-- this question should be a mandatory prompt on SO whenever a new user tries to post a question `:)`

Comment: @alex: function
@Sime: Not at all. No errors, it just somehow doesn't work.

Comment: @Carlos Could you post the generated HTML source code instead? This PHP stuff is not very useful. (View source in the browser)

Comment: @Sime Edited, check the js code.

Comment: @Carlos Are the input boxes added to the page when you call addpago()? what happens when you call sumpagos() manually?

Comment: @Carlos: What happens if you remove the line `document.getElementById('pagos').innerHTML+="<br />";`? Does that fix it for you?

Comment: @Sime: Yes they are added correctly. How can I call the function manually? @sarcastyx I'll try but I don't think so.

Comment: @Carlos Just run `sumpagos()` in the console. If you don't know how to run JavaScript in the console, the instructions are here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: Nevermind, I got an error from calling the function. Actually sumpagos is throwing that document.getElementById("monto" + i) is null.

Comment: How about Firefox 3? I tried ctrl+shift+k and it's not working.

Comment: @Carlos Yes, I was suspecting that..

Comment: Okay, I fixed the function and it's working properly. However I still can't call it when I make the box lose the focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this should make it work:

```
function sumpagos() {
    var total = 0,
        monto;

    for(var i=1; i <= cantpagos; i++) {
        monto = document.getElementById('monto' + i);
        if ( monto != null ) {
            total += +monto.value;
        }
    }    
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '$' + total;
}
```

---

Try this:

```
var monto = document.createElement('input');
monto.type = 'text';
monto.name = monto.id = 'monto' + cantpagos;
monto.onblur = sumpagos;
document.getElementById('pagos').appendChild(monto);
```

---

**Update:**

I believe this line of code is the cause of your issue:

```
document.getElementById('pagos').innerHTML+="<br />";
```

Demo without that line: http://jsfiddle.net/A7aPA/
Demo with that line: http://jsfiddle.net/A7aPA/1/

As you can see, the first demo works, the second one doesn't.

Remove that line and it should work...

Comment: @Carlos Strange, if works fine in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A7aPA/ I don't understand this. It either has to work, or an error must be thrown. There is no third option here. Are you sure that no error is thrown?

Comment: Sure that no error is thrown, I'm checking the error console. Whenever I add an alert to the function, it's not displayed, so I can say for sure there must be some kind of problem when the function is attached to the input element and not in the function itself.

Comment: @Carlos You have to make sure that inside the `addpago` function the identifier name `sumpagos` refers to the correct function. Try `console.log(sumpagos)` from within the `addpago` function. Is the correct function logged?

Comment: @Carlos Do you have Firebug in Firefox? do you have Chrome installed?

Comment: I do have Firebug but not Chrome.

Comment: @Carlos In Firebug, there is a Console tab. When you open it, you should see the result of `console.log(sumpagos);`.

Comment: The result logged is sumpagos() with a link which leads me to the function.

Comment: By the way, the code generated when the child is appended is <input type="text" id="monto0" name="monto0">. Doesn't it lack the onBlur element?

Comment: @Carlos I've run out of ideas. If you could put the page online, I would be able to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Carlos Try `console.dir(monto);` instead. That will log the entire object. Then you can open it up and check if the `onblur` property is set correctly.

Comment: Sure. By the way, if I add the onBlur element manually, it works properly. Here's the page: http://www.codesin.cl/delacosta/IngresoPagos_Costa.php ("Elegir Curso", then any button, then any "Elegir Concepto", then "Añadir un pago" for adding the input elements. That button calls the function dynamically)

Comment: @Carlos I'm baffled. Inside the addpago function the monto element has an onblur property, but once we append the element to the page using appendChild, the onblur property is emptied. I really would like to know why this happens...

Comment: @Carlos I've figured it out `:)`

Comment: That's extremely weird, but thank you, that will be of a huge help. I'll do a bit of research, but any help is welcome.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! Then, what can I do to add the br element?

Comment: @Carlos This should do it: `document.getElementById('pagos').appendChild( document.createElement('br') );`

Comment: How do I remove these br elements then? Can I just use the removeChild function?

Comment: @Carlos If you want more information on the cause of your issue, the full report is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113105/manipulating-innerhtml-removes-the-event-handler-of-a-child-element) `:)`

Comment: Oh wow, you always learn something new. I'll make sure to not make that mistake again. Thank you!

Comment: @Carlos Yea, this was a valuable lesson for both of us `:)`