# change the order of elements to the top

Tags: javascript

```
   <div id="container">
        <div id="1">1</div>
        <div id="2">2</div>
        <div id="3">3</div>
        <div id="4">4</div>
   </div>
```

how to move the `div` #4 to the top using pure javascript
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742305/changing-the-order-of-elements-using-javasript) but it's working only to move elements to the bottom. for example that will work to move #1 to the bottom. it will work to move #4 to the top by moving all the other elements to the bottom. isn't there a direct way to move #4 to the top?.

Comment: Better use jQuery or other suitable javaScript framework

Comment: my website is nearly done. I don't want to add a framework just for this feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var _4th = document.getElementById('4'); // BTW. numeric IDs are not valid
var parent = _4th.parentNode;
var _1st = parent.firstChild;

parent.insertBefore(_4th, _1st);
```

a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FuFtF/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var el = document.getElementById("4")​;
container.insertBefore(el, container.firstChild);
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery solution is,

Your HTML is,

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="1">1</div>
        <div id="2">2</div>
        <div id="3">3</div>
        <div id="4">4</div>
   </div>  ​
```

Some additional css,

```
#container {
    border:1px solid #888;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#container div{
    border:1px solid #Cda12a;
    margin:5px;
    text-align:center;
    height:25px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
}
```

​ And the JavaScript code is,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#container" ).sortable();
    $( "#container" ).disableSelection();
});​
```

Please refer working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bpRAu/)

Answer (score -2):

```
jQuery("#4").before(jQuery("#1").html());
```

try this