# Change index (order) of elements via plain JS

Tags: javascript, dom

Today I have a question: How to change index of elements via plain JS?
I have this example code:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="f6x1"></div>
    <div class="f6x2"></div>
    <div class="f6x3"></div>
</div>
```

So I want to change order of (for example) first element, like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="f6x2"></div>
    <div class="f6x1"></div>
    <div class="f6x3"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any "non-laging" example how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7742305/1794631

Comment: @rmorrin Yes, i've read it, but it's not really fast. Any suggestion?

Comment: @rmorrin By the way, I want to change order, not add element to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select element and the move it before the next element after the second:

```js
var first = document.querySelector('.f6x1'),
    next  = first.nextElementSibling;

first.parentNode.insertBefore(first, next.nextElementSibling);
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <div class="f6x1">1</div>
    <div class="f6x2">2</div>
    <div class="f6x3">3</div>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)
- [Node.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)
- [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to order the elements in any order you need:

first, start indexing using `data-*`-attributes:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div data-index="1" class="f6x1"></div>
    <div data-index="2" class="f6x2"></div>
    <div data-index="3" class="f6x3"></div>
</div>
```

Second, use a function to reorder, something like:

```js
var sortElement = document.querySelector('[data-sortable]');

document.querySelector('#buttonblock').addEventListener('click', doSort);

function doSort(e) {
  var origin = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (/button/i.test(origin.nodeName)) {
    var sortorder = origin.getAttribute('data-order').split(',');
    orderElements(sortElement, sortorder);
  }
  return true;
}

function orderElements(elementRoot, order) {
  var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
  while(order.length) {
    var current = order.shift();
    var element = elementRoot.querySelector('[data-index="'+current+'"]');
    if (element) {
     placeholder.appendChild(element);
    }
  }
  elementRoot.innerHTML = '';
  elementRoot.innerHTML = placeholder.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div data-sortable="true" class="foo">
  <div data-index="1" class="f6x1">f6x1</div>
  <div data-index="2" class="f6x2">f6x2</div>
  <div data-index="3" class="f6x3">f6x3</div>
</div>

<div id="buttonblock">
  <button data-order="2,1,3">sort 2, 1, 3</button>
  <button data-order="3,2,1">sort 3, 2, 1</button>
  <button data-order="3,1,2">sort 3, 1, 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kooilnc I think it's very large code (see dfsq's answer), but it shows another way how to do it :) By the way, I don't want to touch the code.