# there are 5 "li" element ,how to exchange the first "li" element and the last "li" element?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<pre>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
</pre>
```

there are 5 "li" element ,i want to exchange the first "li" element and the last "li" element?
just like this:

```
<pre>
<ul>
<li>5</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>1</li>
</ul>
</pre>
```

Comment: I don't understand **`change`** in your question. what does it exactly mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is similar to this one: [Changing the order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742305/changing-the-order-of-elements)

Easier if you have unique ids, but it is possible with tag names.

```js
(function() {
  let list = document.querySelectorAll("pre > ul > li")
  list[0].parentNode.insertBefore(list[4], list[0])
  list[0].parentNode.append(list[0]);
})();
```

```html
<pre>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive idea is to get a list of li's, then you pop the first time, then push the same item onto the list, then replace all the children.

Alternatively, Get the content of the first Li, last Li, then replace the values.
The first and the second options are semantically different. One *copies* nodes, while the other merely copies inner text.