# JS events. Only one of the event handler function is being called?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

**Hi everybody!** 
I have a problem and I have no idea how to fix it!

I have a simple HTML page with a button:

```
<input type = "submit" value = "ok" onclick="f1()"/>
```

I also have a script on this page:

```
<script>    
function f2()    
{           
   var firstBtn = document.createElement("button");         
   firstBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("firstBtn"));
   document.body.appendChild(firstBtn);
   var xmlhttp = CreateRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
         var response = xmlhttp.responseText;               
         document.body.innerHTML += response;
       }
   }
   firstBtn.onclick = function()
   {
     alert("inside f2 onclick");
     xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php",true);
     xmlhttp.send();
   }

}    
function f3()  
{  
   var secondBtn = document.createElement("button");            
   secondBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("secondBtn"));       
   document.body.appendChild(secondBtn);
   var xmlhttp = CreateRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
         var response = xmlhttp.responseText;               
         document.body.innerHTML += response;
       }
   }
   secondBtn.onclick = function()
   {
     alert("inside f3 onclick");
     xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php",true);
     xmlhttp.send();
   }
}  
function f1()    
{  
  f2();  
  f3();  
}  
function CreateRequest()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)              
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari       
    else                    
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// code for IE6, IE5 

    return xmlhttp;
}
</script>
```

So now, when I click one of the buttons (firstBtn or secondBtn), another one is not responding to the click event! Does anybody know why?

Comment: See the error on firebug console.

Comment: Seems like a scope problem on xmlhttp variables inside click handlers.

Comment: What do you want to do? Are both of the buttons need to launch the sam e function?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to say. I tried above code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pTvhE/ and it works good. Means both buttons respond to click event as expected.

Comment: @PrateekShukla There is no error on firebug console

Comment: Try doing your script include after the button html. That should work. I updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pTvhE/1/ to add the onclick from js and it worked.

Comment: @vishwanath I'm trying to say that when you click button "ok" you will get two other buttons - firstBtn and secondBtn, but if you will click firstBtn you will see alert box (inside f2 onclick) and after that if you will click secondBtn you will get nothing.. sorry for my english!

Comment: well that's not happening, you can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/pTvhE

Comment: @vishwanath Yes, this works fine in jsfiddle.net, I guess it because you can't include php script there. But this doesn't work for me!

Comment: Can you share the response of your php script?

Comment: Found the Answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113105/manipulating-innerhtml-removes-the-event-handler-of-a-child-element

Comment: You are doing += with body innnerHTML, which is the cause of losing events.

Comment: @vishwanath Ok, I gotcha! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vishwanath said (see comments to this question), when I doing

```
 document.body.innerHTML += response;
```

I'm destroying and recreating all the content of my page therefore I'm losing my events.