# Can't append contents of page to parent element

Tags: javascript

I have grabbed the contents of a HTML file which i want to append to an element.

The contents of the HTML is shown like this:

`console.log(data);`

Output:

```
<style>
    .data{
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
<div id="data">
</div>
```

I then append it to a parent element like this:

```
function merge(data,id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    console.clear();
    console.log(el);
    console.log(data);

    el.appendChild(data);       
}
```

The output for `el` does show the correct element that I am trying to append to.

But i seem to get this error:

`Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`

What does the error mean, and how do I correct the error?

Comment: try `.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', data);` -- `appendChild` expects a DOM node, not a string...

Comment: Can you tell me what is the element `el`?

Comment: @WhiteHat thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create the objects:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = data;
```

This will cause `data` to be turned into *HTML* objects that the *DOM* can use which are stored in the `childNodes` attribute of `div`.

```
var children = div.childNodes;
for(var i in children)
    el.appendChild(children[i]);
```

So, you can create some functions like:

```
function interpret_data(data) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = data;
    return div.childNodes;
}

function addChildrenTo(children, elem) {
    for(var i in children)
        elem.appendChild(children[i]);
}

function merge(data, id){
    addChildrenTo(interpret_data(data), document.getElementById(id));
}
```

That should do the trick!

**NOTE:** These functions aren't bullet proof so play with them to fit your needs:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for innerHTML property, exactly as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript).

The reason it doesn't work is that appendChild is a method of DOM node, expecting a DOM node - you are supplying text data instead. See the method definition [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).

Comment: No. Inner HTML will replace my parent's current content and any event listeners tied to said contents.... thats not ideal. Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5113120/1076743

Comment: Then [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is your friend, as @WhiteHat suggested.