# Javascript addEventListener on 3 links, only 1 working

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am trying to add event listeners on the fly on my links with the following code (that is called 3 times with a different this.newsPost.id of course):

```
document.getElementById('user_news_post_comment_add_button_show_form_' + this.newsPost.id).innerHTML = 'yahoooooo' + this.newsPost.id;
document.getElementById('user_news_post_comment_add_button_show_form_' + this.newsPost.id).addEventListener('click', function() {alert('alert');});
```

The first line is a debug line, to see if it was a problem accessing the DOM event. But surprisingly, the first line updates the 3 links with yahooooo1 or 2 or 3, but the second line attaches the event only on the third link.

I guess you don't have enough information to solve the problem, but maybe you can give me some hints where i should look.

---

To provide more information, I am looping here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < newsPostArray.length; ++i) {
    if (i != 0) {
        container.innerHTML += '<hr />';
    }

    this.showNewsPostSingle(container, newsPostArray[i]);
}
```

Then I have:

```
UserNewsPostList.prototype.showNewsPostSingle = function (container, newsPost) {
    var content = '<div class="user_news_post">';
    content += '<div id="user_news_post_comment_' + newsPost.id + '" class="user_news_post_comment"></div>';
    content += '</div>';
    container.innerHTML += content;
    new UserNewsPostListComment(newsPost).show(document.getElementById('user_news_post_comment_' + newsPost.id));
};
```

Which calls:

```
function UserNewsPostListComment(newsPost) {
    this.newsPost = newsPost;
}

UserNewsPostListComment.prototype.show = function(container) {
    var content = '';

    content += this.getNewsPostHTMLSingleCommentPartAdd();
    container.innerHTML = content;

    window.console.log(this.newsPost.id);

    document.getElementById('user_news_post_comment_add_button_show_form_' + this.newsPost.id).innerHTML = 'yahoooooo' + this.newsPost.id;
    document.getElementById('user_news_post_comment_add_button_show_form_' + this.newsPost.id).addEventListener('click', function() {alert('attachEvents');});
};

UserNewsPostListComment.prototype.getNewsPostHTMLSingleCommentPartAdd = function() {
    var content = '<div class="user_news_post_comment_add">';

    content += '<a id="user_news_post_comment_add_button_show_form_' + this.newsPost.id + '">LINK</a>';

    content += '</div>';

    return content;
};
```

Console shows:
    4
    3
    2
    1

---

Additional update: By doing step by step debugging in Chrome with the dev tools, it seems each links loses the click event as soon as the next

```
 container.innerHTML += '<hr />';
```

is executed in the first loop. Any reason why appending to a parent innerHTML (this one or another one) would delete the event listener added?

Comment: You should show just a bit more of code so we can understand what's the closure of `this` or get an eye to your wrapping environment.

Comment: Would be even better if you can post a minimal but verifiable sample code, HTML, JS...

Comment: I believe you need to use IIFE. Please post more code for us to help you better.

Comment: Posted more code, and since the innerHTML of the link is updated with the proper id in the first getElementById, i don't think the ID is the issue: I get yahoooo1, yahooooo2, yahooooo3, yahoooo4 shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the line by line debug, I found out the next .innerHTML += was removing the events.

From that, I was able to find this problem:
[Manipulating innerHTML removes the event handler of a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113105/manipulating-innerhtml-removes-the-event-handler-of-a-child-element/5113132#5113132)
and I was able to solve mine by using:

```
.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'test');
// instead of
.innerHTML += 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your code and its working fine for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/zqt4bjtt/

following JS code used for simulation. Please see the jsfiddle for full simulation

```
id = 1;
while(id < 4){
    document.getElementById('user_news_post_comment_add_button_show_form_' + id).innerHTML = 'yahoooooo' + id;
    document.getElementById('user_news_post_comment_add_button_show_form_' + id).addEventListener('click', function() {alert(this.id);});
  id++;

}
```

Possibly the error maybe your this.newsPost.id is not changing. Hard to tell with the snippet provided