# Why doesn't addEventListener listen to me?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Why does addEventListener only cooperate with the `CANCEL` label element and not the first, even if I remove the second? I don't get any error messages in console.

```js
var ctrl = document.createElement('div');
ctrl.id = 'ctrl';

var showhide = document.createElement('label');
showhide.id = 'showhide';
showhide.innerHTML = 'Show/hide output';
showhide.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false;');
showhide.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('Show/hide');
});

var cancel = document.createElement('label');
cancel.id = 'cancel';
cancel.innerHTML = 'CANCEL';
cancel.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false;');
//document.getElementById('showhide').insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', cancel.outerHTML);
cancel.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('cancel');
});

ctrl.appendChild(showhide)
ctrl.innerHTML += ' | '
ctrl.appendChild(cancel)
document.body.appendChild(ctrl)
```

Comment: `ctrl.innerHTML += ' | '` doesn't append, it destroys everything in the element, and creates new content. The event listener was added to the original element, but not to the newly-created.

Comment: huh! that was easy, thank you. Doesn't `+=` append?

Comment: Nope, it's just a shortcut to `innerHTML = innerHTML + ' | '`. Use `insertAdjacentHTML` or create and append a textnode.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit in your above code is the line with `ctrl.innerHTML += ' | ';` Comment out the code and it will work fine.
The reason is that when you use `innerHTML` the content is re-assigned and re-evaluated destroying the existing events. [Here is an example explained in StackOverflow answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113120/3081756)