# Replace HTML with innerHTML - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I need to write a JS functionality that reads an entire HTML document and replace a text with some other text.

HTML -

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="aId" href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link1 </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="bId" href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link2 </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link3 </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript code -

```
var strMessage1 = document.getElementById("aId") ;
var first = 'target="_blank"';
var second = 'target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick="alert(\'Hello World!\')"';

strMessage1.innerHTML = strMessage1.innerHTML.replace(first, second) ;
```

The javascript should be able to run through entire HTML and replace the first var with the second var (defined in the script), wherever found. This is an example of just the first id - 'aId'.

Question - How would the script cover and replace contents in

- bId id?
- Link3, which has no id?

as well.

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/nikhil_gupta/rzy3ajhx/.

Note - No use of jQuery.

Comment: Look up [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and stay away from w3schools IMO. eg `const anchor3 = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(3) > a')`

Comment: `document.getElementById("aId").innerHTML` will give you `" Link1 "` and the replacement code won't work. You should use `outerHTML` instead.

Comment: *The javascript should be able to run through all the **input element** of HTML* But your example doesn't have any `input` elements. It shows you working on **`a`** elements.

Comment: @31piy `outerHTML` will not do what you think it does. It will replace the `a` element entirely with `'target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick="alert(\'Hello World!\')"'`

Comment: @ScottMarcus -- OP clearly wants to replace the occurrence of `'target="_blank"'` with  `'target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick="alert(\'Hello World!\')"'`. I believe `outerHTML` works perfectly fine for it.

Answer (score 1):

**[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** alters the ***content*** of an element (what's between the opening and closing tags). Your code attempts to alter the ***value of an element's attribute***. These are not the same thing.

Also, it's important to understand the implications of using `innerHTML` (and `outerHTML`).

- They both cause the DOM to have to be re-built and then re-painted
  and re-flowed which is very expensive in terms of resources.
- Their use will also remove any previously set up event handlers.
- They open security holes in your application.
- They are usually accompanied by gobs and gobs of string
  concatenations and nested quotes.

To change the value of an element's attribute, just access the HTML attribute you want to modify as a property of the JavaScript object or use the **[`element.setAttribute(attributeName, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)** DOM method.

> Question - How would the script cover and replace contents in
>
> - bId id?
> - Link3, which has no id?
>
> as well.

When you want to alter more than one element, you need to get them into a collection or array and then you can loop over them. Getting them into a group  can be done in many different ways that doesn't have to do with `id`s at all (by tag name, by CSS class, by position in the document, by attribute values, etc.). In your example, if we wanted to modify all the links that were inside of bullets that have `target=_blank` as their `href` value, we could target them by position and attribute value with a CSS selector and the **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** method. You'll notice in my example below, I've removed the `id` attributes completely from the HTML and the code still works.

Lastly, you should not be using inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`, etc.) to configure event handling callback functions. That is a 25+ year old technique that gets copied and pasted by every new web developer without an understanding of **[why it shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**. Instead, use modern, standards-based code and the **[`.addEventListener()` DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

```js
// Get the elements you wish to work on into an Array
// Here, we're selecting <a> elements that have an href attribute with a value of _blank 
// that are direct children of <li> elements:
var elementsToChange = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li > a[target='_blank']"));

// We only need to worry about what's going to change
var newRel = 'noopener noreferrer'

// This will be the click event callback function
function doAlert(){
  alert('Hello World!');
}

// Loop over the array
elementsToChange.forEach(function(element){
  // Just access the HTML attribute you want to modify as a property of the JavaScript object
  element.rel = newRel;
    
  // Or, use the DOM API
  element.setAttribute("rel", newRel); 
  
  // Either way the DOM API should always be used to set up event handlers
  element.addEventListener("click", doAlert);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">I will be modified by the code</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">I WON'T be modified by the code!</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">I will be modified by the code</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is your rel attribute: `rel="rel="noopener noreferrer""`. The info in the post is good, I just find it ironic that you posted a broken solution multiple times while giving another user a snarky response to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean outerHTML

http://jsfiddle.net/rzy3ajhx/1/

```
strMessage1.outerHTML = strMessage1.outerHTML.replace(first, second);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to change the attributes in the html tag.
You can't use `.innerHTML` or `.replace` to do that, it just changes the content inside the html tag.
To solve for your question, you can use `.getAttribute()`, `.setAttribute()`, or `.createAttribute()` method.
Something similar with your code, and it works:

```
var strMessage1 = document.getElementById("aId");
strMessage1.setAttribute("rel", "noopener noreferrer");
strMessage1.setAttribute("onClick", "alert(\'Hello World!\')")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outerHTML` to replace the occurrence of the contents of `first` with the contents of `second`. You may select the second `a` using the same `document.getElementById` call.

For third one, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` and get the last item of the returned collection.

```js
var strMessage1 = document.getElementById("aId");
var strMessage2 = document.getElementById("bId");
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var strMessage3 = anchors[anchors.length - 1];

var first = 'target="_blank"';
var second = 'target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick="alert(\'Hello World!\')"';

strMessage1.outerHTML = strMessage1.outerHTML.replace(first, second);
strMessage2.outerHTML = strMessage2.outerHTML.replace(first, second);
strMessage3.outerHTML = strMessage3.outerHTML.replace(first, second);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="aId" href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link1 </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="bId" href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link2 </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link3 </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Better coding practices:**

- Use `setAttribute()` to set individual attributes of an element instead of doing a replace. This will prevent unwanted bugs.
- Instead of selecting individual elements by using `document.getElementById` and `document.querySelectorAll`, you may use one `document.querySelectorAll` and loop on the collection to replace the contents.

Answer (score 0):

- Q1:bId id?

Ans1: I don't know which kind of element is you need. So, I catch all of the  
tags. There is a simple way to get elements: `document.querySelectorAll("query")`

- Q2:Link3, which has no id?

Ans2: as Q1. Element that don't has id is fine.

- Q3:edited tag not work.

Ans 3: *.innerHTML* is for `<a>*here*</a>`, you need to edit attribute so you need to call *.outerHTML*

Refs:

- [document.queryselectorall()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)
- [innerhtml-vs-outerhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941911/javascript-innerhtml-vs-outerhtml)

```js
var all_a_tag = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < all_a_tag.length; i++) {
  var elem = all_a_tag[i];
  var first = 'target="_blank"';
  var second = 'target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick="alert(\'Hello World!\')"';

  elem.outerHTML = elem.outerHTML.replace(first, second);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="aId" href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link1 </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="bId" href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link2 </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"> Link3 </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```