# All buttons lose function after I use once

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a button that displays a custom dialogue box.  If the user selects 'cancel', the dialogue box should be removed from the DOM and no further action is taken.  If they click 'Start Delete', it should proceed with code.

The dialogue box shows and hides correctly, however, after I cancel and hide the dialogue box, the button no longer works to display the dialogue box again.

I have created a popup class that uses a template string to display the popup and I then inject it into the DOM.  The popup takes a callback in the constructor, which I use to hide the popup.

Please see the following JS Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/khgriffi259/vs6r5ake/13/

```js
  class Popup {

    constructor(title, message, callback) {
      this.title = title;
      this.message = message;
      this.callback = callback;
      this.container = document.querySelector('body');
      this.result = '';
    }
  
    init() {
      const popup = `
          <div class="popup-wrapper">
              <div class="popup bg-white p-1">
                  <div class="popup-close">X</div>
                  <div class="popup-content ">
                      <h2 class="">${this.title}</h2>
                      <p class="p-1 my-2">${this.message}</p>
                      <div class="dialogue_buttons my-1">
                          <button class="btn popup-no" >Cancel</button>
                          <button class="btn btn-danger my-1 popup-yes" >Start Delete</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>  
      `;
      this.container.innerHTML += popup;
  
      this.container.querySelector('.popup-no').addEventListener('click', () => this.cancelListener());
      this.container.querySelector('.popup-yes').addEventListener('click', () => this.startListener());
  
    }
  
    cancelListener() {
      this.result = false;
    
        this.callback();
    //   if (this.callback !== undefined) {
    //     this.callback(this.result);
    //   }
    }
  
    startListener() {
      this.result  = true;
      if (this.callback !== undefined) {
        this.callback();
      }
    }
 

     
       getResult() {
         console.log(this.result) ;
        return this.result;
        }

  
  }

    //end of Popup Class

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click',  e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    
    const confirmDelete = new Popup(
      'Delete', 
      'This will permanently delete this experience record.',
      ()=>{
        console.log('hello');
        let elem = document.querySelector('.popup-wrapper');
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        
      }
    );
    confirmDelete.init();
     }
})
```

```html
<button>
click me
</button>
```

I expect the popup to hide and for the button to be functional to generate a new Popup if user clicks the button again.

Comment: Apparently, using `innerHTML` to change the HTML contents of a node will remove the events in the node, as seen [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113120).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below for a fixed version of your code.

The only change is from

```
this.container.innerHTML += popup;
```

to

```
this.container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', popup);
```

The reason your original code fails is that `.innerHTML` serializes the DOM tree back to an HTML string, appends `popup`, then the assignment to `.innerHTML` reparses the whole thing, recreating all elements from scratch. As a side effect, your original `click` listener is lost because it's still attached to the old `button` element. Assigning to `.innerHTML` means you get a completely new DOM tree.

As [the documentation for `insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) states:

> The **`insertAdjacentHTML()`** method of the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position. *It does not reparse the element it is being used on, and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside that element.* This avoids the extra step of serialization, making it much faster than direct [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) manipulation.

(Emphasis mine.)

```js
  class Popup {

    constructor(title, message, callback) {
      this.title = title;
      this.message = message;
      this.callback = callback;
      this.container = document.querySelector('body');
      this.result = '';
    }
  
    init() {
      const popup = `
          <div class="popup-wrapper">
              <div class="popup bg-white p-1">
                  <div class="popup-close">X</div>
                  <div class="popup-content ">
                      <h2 class="">${this.title}</h2>
                      <p class="p-1 my-2">${this.message}</p>
                      <div class="dialogue_buttons my-1">
                          <button class="btn popup-no" >Cancel</button>
                          <button class="btn btn-danger my-1 popup-yes" >Start Delete</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>  
      `;
      this.container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', popup);
  
      this.container.querySelector('.popup-no').addEventListener('click', () => this.cancelListener());
      this.container.querySelector('.popup-yes').addEventListener('click', () => this.startListener());
  
    }
  
    cancelListener() {
      this.result = false;
    
        this.callback();
    //   if (this.callback !== undefined) {
    //     this.callback(this.result);
    //   }
    }
  
    startListener() {
      this.result  = true;
      if (this.callback !== undefined) {
        this.callback();
      }
    }
 

     
       getResult() {
         console.log(this.result) ;
        return this.result;
        }

  
  }

    //end of Popup Class

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click',  e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    
    const confirmDelete = new Popup(
      'Delete', 
      'This will permanently delete this experience record.',
      ()=>{
        console.log('hello');
        let elem = document.querySelector('.popup-wrapper');
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        
      }
    );
    confirmDelete.init();
     }
})
```

```html
<button>
click me
</button>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for the quick and concise edit.  Looks like there are multiple solutions to this issue (braza also had a working solution below).  Anyway, I did not know that the innerHTML method serializes the HTML  to a string. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When you edit the `innerHTML` of the `body` you clear the `eventListener` on the `button`.

I've updated the fiddle to a working version here https://jsfiddle.net/n5k9rsbe/6/

There are 2 ways to get this working:

1 - Create a container element and modify that

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = '...';
```

2 - Use `appendChild` on the `body`

```
const elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = popup
this.container.appendChild(elem)
```

Comment: Awesome.  Looks like there's multiple solutions to this issue. 
 Good learning experience. Thank you!