# Javascript cancels events when the inner HTML of the parent element is mofidied

Tags: javascript, events, innerhtml

I ran into something weird playing with events on Javascript, I tried adding events to an element, and modifying the parent element inner HTML deleted the events, here is an example :

```
const content = document.body
const p = document.createElement('p')
p.innerHTML = "I am just a text element."

p.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    console.log("The event works..")
})

content.appendChild(p)
content.innerHTML += "<div> </div>"
```

Now, clicking on the "p" element should trigger the event but the last line "content.innerHTML..." prevents it. It somehow delete the event.

I know modifying the inner HTML like this is not a good practice, but still, can someone explain why the events are deleted ?

Thank you !

Comment: The `p` you created and the `p` you manually wrote via `innerHTML` are not one and the same.

Comment: indeed! add the listener to the `content` instead, and reach the `p` via `event.target.closest('p')`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks you for your answers !  
I know the two "p" are not the same, i'm trying to call the first "p" event. I could had only a letter or every other tag in the content inner HTML, I will fix my post to make more sense.
Also, I'm not trying to fix a problem, I want to understand why modifying the inner HTML of the parent element delete the event..

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113105/manipulating-innerhtml-removes-the-event-handler-of-a-child-element

Comment: Indeed this is, thanks you I couldn't find it myself, should I delete my post then ?

Comment: It's not that it deletes the event - it's that *you* delete the element the event was bound to, by overwriting the contents of its container element. The `p` ceases to exist, so its event cannot be called.

Comment: Yes I delete the element but I thought that by recreating it, it would recreate the events to. But I found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113105/manipulating-innerhtml-removes-the-event-handler-of-a-child-element that the attributes cannot be mapped into inner HTML..
Thank you !

Comment: You haven't recreated the element; you've made a new element. That's the takeaway here.